# There is a method to these equations

Tags: logical-deduction

Please find the method used to get these equations and solve the last one.

[image]

> The answer is a positive integer.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to argue that the question mark should be replaced with:

> $28$

The rule is as follows:

> Add or subtract (as required by the signs) the **total number of 'intersections' of lines** (including at corners) in each shape, then multiply the result by the **number of shapes depicted**.
>
>  Thus the cross-shape has 1 intersection and 1 shape, and $1*1=1$
>
>  The lone triangle has 3 intersections and 1 shape, and $3*1=3$
>
>  The rectangle-triangle combo has 13 intersections (7 corners, 6 crossovers), to which we add the next rectangle's 4 intersections, giving 17 intersections in total. We then multiply by 3 (since there are 3 shapes, counting the overlaid ones separately), and thus $17*3=51$
>
>  So, finally, for the last row we have $13-3-3=7$ intersections, and multiply by 4 (since there are 4 shapes), and thus $7*4=28$

Comment: BX. Lbh sbhaq nabgure jnl. Urer vf fbzrguvat gb zhyy bire. Gur gevnatyr vf hcfvqr qbja. Abj hcfvqr qbja bs gur ahzore bs vagrefrpgvbaf vf___

Comment: Guerr hcfvqr qbja vf R? Guvegrra hcfvqr qbja vf RV? Fvk hcfvqr qbja vf avar? V qba'g trg ubj nal bs gubfr yrnqf gb svsgl-bar, gubhtu.

Answer (score 1):

This involves some wild guesses but maybe it is what you had in mind.

Start with a triangle being 3 and guess that the square is a 4.

This gives 47 for the symbol that consists of a square and a triangle standing on a corner. So next guess is that this represents a 2 digit number, then the triangle on a corner is a 7.

This gives 47 - 7 - 7 = 33 for the last equation.

Answer (score 0):

I see wild guessing is the name of the game. I’ll give it a go. Assuming

> interlaced shapes mean multiplication, we can solve the third equation to make the square equal 17 and upside down triangle equal 2. This will make the last equation 34-2-2=30.